# Encrypt and decrypt with swap

Tags: java, encryption

I have to write an encrypt and decrypt function. Converting from plain text to binary then swapping the second and third bits. I was thinking about changing the plain text to ASCII values then converting those to binary but I’m confused on how to swap them and decrypt it.

Comment: If you swap two bits, then on average 50% of the bytes will stay the same.

Comment: What Henry said. Also, unless you have some sort of secret input to your algorithm, that'd be encoding, not encryption, because anyone could reverse it. That being said, in Java you convert a string to bytes with the String.getBytes method.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not secure you can try this:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] text="Hello World".toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            text[i]=encodingDecoding(text[i]);
        }
        System.out.println( new String(text).equals("Di``c,[c~`h"));

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            text[i]=encodingDecoding(text[i]);
        }
        System.out.println( new String(text).equals("Hello World"));
    }

    public static char encodingDecoding(int n){
        int turningOffBit= n & 0xF3;//0xF3= 1111 0011
        //Extracting inverted bit 2 and 3 with a bit mask
        int bit2and3= n ^ 0xC;//0xC=  0000 1100
        return (char)(turningOffBit | bit2and3);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is flipping,bits, not swapping them. Furthermore it could be easier achieved with `n ^ 0xC`

Comment: You are right i made a mistake in my thinking process, but `n ^0xC` should be enough